# MiBand 2 - parsing steps from received bytes

Tags: java, android

I'm making Android app that comunicates with MiBand2 and I'm using this code - https://github.com/fraperleo/MonitoringMiBand2.
How to parse number of steps from received bytes?
Received bytes - [12, 93, 4, 0, 0, -71, 2, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0]. Band is showing 1117 steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class **ByteBuffer** and wrap the bytes and get the integer value.

```
byte[] miBandResponse = {12, 93, 4, 0, 0, -71, 2,24};
int steps = ByteBuffer.wrap(miBandResponse).getInt();
```

Also you can use **BigInteger**:

```
  byte[] miBandResponse = {10, -116}; //2700 steps.
    int i = new BigInteger(miBandResponse).intValue();
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've already tried that and I get really big number (with 8, 9 digits - a lot bigger than the number on the band), so I don't think that's the only thing which needs to be done. I assume that byte on each position represents something and that I don't need all of them, but don't know which byte is what.

Comment: Hey, I've figured it!
byte[] tmp = {miBandResponse[2], miBandResponse[1]};
int steps = new BigInteger(tmp).intValue();

Why first and second byte? I have no idea!

Comment: I don't know how to treat the data. I am gonna get one Mi band 3 soon. I will take a look! :D